# Retrieve field information form Firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I want to retrieve name of a user which is inside a field in firestore.
The whole sequence in given in image below.

[image: Sequence]

I want to get the string value 'a' which is inside (chatroom->a_qaz->users->'a').

I am trying to get it with this code but its not working. How to get the field information.

```
getOtherUserByUsername() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatroom")
        .doc("chatRoomId")
        .get();
```

Comment: Just replace "chatRoomId" with "a_qaz" and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's get the document from your collection.

collection.doc(), as per [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc), gets the actual ID as parameter. In your case, you need to specify "a_qaz". After that, you get the document and then you can read the fields. Your code should look like this:

```
let chatRoom = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatroom")
        .doc("a_qaz")
        .get();
let users = chatRoom.get("users");
```

users will store, then, the list of users that's in that field.